# How to change background color of td elements based on th using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stuck with a challenge to change the background color of **td** elements based on the **th** class. Below is the html code, which has **th** class called **bots**, I've to change the background color of all the **td** elements below the **bots** class.

```html
<table border="1" class="CSSTableGenerator" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Properties</th>
    <th class="bots">J10</th>
    <th>J11</th>
    <th>J12</th>
    <th>J13</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GenerateAlternateTagUrlDroplet</td>
    <td>alternateTagConfiguration</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/com//jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/com//jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/com//jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/com//jec/website/seo/</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>AlternateTagUrlDroplet</td>
    <td>tagConfiguration</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/jec/website/seo/</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can someone please help me with jquery code to achieve this?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to provide your current CSS?

Comment: Thanks Caelan for looking into this. Well, I don't have a proper css. I'm just  dynamically adding class using jquery $('.trueValue').addClass('foo'); and in my css file, I'm setting up the background color like this .foo {background-color: green;}. This is for td elements only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map()` to return array of indexes with `.bots` class and then change css of `td` with same index.

```js
var bots = $('tr th.bots').map(function() {
  return $(this).index();
}).get()

$('tr:not(:first) td').each(function() {
  if (bots.indexOf($(this).index()) != -1) $(this).css('background', 'blue')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="CSSTableGenerator" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Properties</th>
    <th class="bots">J10</th>
    <th>J11</th>
    <th class="bots">J12</th>
    <th>J13</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GenerateAlternateTagUrlDroplet</td>
    <td>alternateTagConfiguration</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/com//jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/com//jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/com//jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/com//jec/website/seo/</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>AlternateTagUrlDroplet</td>
    <td>tagConfiguration</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/jec/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="trueValue">/jec/website/seo/</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad. Apologies for this unclear question. I have other th bot classes. Your code works perfectly for the first th column. What if my code has multiple th classes? How can I change the color based on th class name? For example, in this case, bots th class. Once again Many Thanks for your answer.

Comment: awesome, this is working but it is changing the background of other tables which are not having bots th class? Any chance we can stop the color being changed for non- bots th classes? I'm sorry, asking too many things here. Appreciate your patience. Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, easiest option is to just add `id` of table like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/980/ or you can add specific class on tables that you want to use these rules.

Comment: awesome, this works perfectly! I don't know how to thank you. But all I can say is you are genious.. Great Thanks Nenad. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to do something along the lines of:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEPVGW?editors=1010)

```
var nthChild = $('.bots').index() + 1; // Add 1 since index starts at 0
$("td:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").css("background", 'yellow');
```

Comment: Thanks @dwreck08 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe get all th.bots index and use that to color the tds.
Assuming you have jQuery:

```
$('th.bots').each(function(){
    $('td:nth-child('+($(this).index() + 1)+')').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Edit: Excluding other tables on same page
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzNZrE

```
$('th.bots').each(function(){
    $(this).parents('table').children().find('td:nth-child('+($(this).index() + 1)+')').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Comment: Updated answer based on your request